# Rdio Quicklists

Tags: unity, 13.04, launcher, webapps, quicklists

**I would like to have "Play/Pause" "Next" and "Previous" buttons in the quicklist for my Rdio.desktop "web app."**

*Detailed Explanation*

The web app can be created either from Chrome (by going to menu > tools > create application shortcuts) or through Unity's web app interface.  Either of these methods puts a .desktop file in `/home/user/.local/share/applications/` which opens a new browser window.

In case you use *chrome*, the result is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open                                                         
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Rdio
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=http://www.rdio.com/
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/user/icons/rdio.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
StartupWMClass=www.rdio.com
```

In the case you use *Unity's web app feature*, the result is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Rdio
Type=Application
Icon=Rdio-www.rdio.com
MimeType=
Actions=S0;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6;S7;S8;S9;S10;
Exec=unity-webapps-runner -n 'UmRpbwA=' -d 'www.rdio.com' %u
```

I want to add something like the following to either .desktop file (preferably the chrome one because Unity web apps don't work correctly) so that I can control playback with a right click:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=PlayPause;Next;Previous;

[PlayPause Shortcut Group]
Name=PlayPause
Exec=google-chrome (some arguments here?) rdio.com/?magic_url=play_pause
TargetEnvironment=Unity

#... (and similarly for next and previous)
```

*However, I don't know what URLs to give it, and how to make it not open new windows but stay in the already open one!*

Comment: You want to right click with your mouse? Where?

Comment: I want to get a quicklist when I right-click on the Rdio web app icon in the dash. Quicklists appear when you right click the icon of an app that supports them. Try with Rhythmbox or Nautilus!

Comment: Generally I can't answer your question (Rdio is not available in my country), but I don't think it will be easy (or even possible)

Comment: It might be possible using Unity's web app feature, since some apps (Gmail?) might be using quicklists. I'm not sure. I think my solution is to switch (back) to Spotify :)

Comment: Yes, apps can use quicklist (it's in .desktop file), but that "magic url" may not exist

Comment: It would probably require building a plugin for Chrome that receives signals from a secondary program -- we'll call it "rdiocontrol". The plugin might listen on a particular TCP/IP port (to make things easy) on localhost. You would set up the quicklist to call 'rdiocontrol pause', at which point rdiocontrol will send a signal through that TCP/IP port that the plugin would catch and act upon. Since the plugin should have full control of the DOM within chrome, it could easily click() the rdio pause button for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a stand-alone Rdio wrapper integrated with Ubuntu. See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/rdio-app-for-ubuntu-desktop for the details.

Installing Rdio in Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 & 12.10 is as easy as adding the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sgringwe/rdio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rdio
```

As for 13.04 and 13.10 users (I'm on 13.10 and this works), just install the deb:

https://code.launchpad.net/~sgringwe/+archive/rdio/+packages

(I found the icons ugly, so I changed the icon in the rdio.desktop file (run `sudo updatedb` and `locate rdio.desktop` to find it) by one I got online.)